# c# backgroundWorker and trackBar

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

Some code:

Function that locks bitmapData:

```
    public static BitmapData LockData(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Rectangle bitmapRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(bitmapRect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        return bitmapData;
    }
```

Function that unlocks bitnapData:

```
    public static void UnlockData(Bitmap bitmap, BitmapData bitmapData)
    {
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    }
```

Function that changes image brightness:

```
    public static void Bright(int bright, BitmapData bitmapData, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        byte nPixelFormat = 0;
        if (bitmapData.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb) nPixelFormat = 3;
        else if (bitmapData.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb) nPixelFormat = 4;

        int max = bitmapData.Height - 1;
        int percent = 0;

        unsafe
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bitmapData.Height; y++)
            {
                byte* pBmpRow = (byte*)(bitmapData.Scan0 + y * bitmapData.Stride);

                for (int x = 0; x < bitmapData.Width; x++)
                {
                    if (worker.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    int bVal = pBmpRow[nPixelFormat * x] + bright;
                    int gVal = pBmpRow[nPixelFormat * x + 1] + bright;
                    int rVal = pBmpRow[nPixelFormat * x + 2] + bright;



                    Clamp(ref bVal);
                    Clamp(ref gVal);
                    Clamp(ref rVal);


                    pBmpRow[nPixelFormat * x] = (byte)bVal;
                    pBmpRow[nPixelFormat * x + 1] = (byte)gVal;
                    pBmpRow[nPixelFormat * x + 2] = (byte)rVal;
                }
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
                int curPercent = (y * 100) / max;

                if (curPercent > percent)
                {
                    percent = curPercent;
                    worker.ReportProgress(percent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In this function i'm checking backgroundWorker abort and updating progress.

Now i'm having w trackbar and numericBox which i'm using to change brightness. When trackbar or numericBox value changes, then backgroundWorker starts. The problem is that, when backgroundWorker is busy and i've changed trackbarValue, backgroundWorker should stop and start again. Now in my code it works liku button. When worker is busy, value changing stops worker, then next value changing starts it.

Code:

```
    private void OnNumericBoxValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        m_trkBarBright.Value = (int)m_numericBright.Value;

        brightValue = m_trkBarBright.Value;
        if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }


        m_btnOK.Focus();
    }


    private void WorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;


        Colors.CopyImgData(m_orgImage, m_tempImage);
        data = Colors.LockData(m_tempImage);

        Colors.Bright(brightValue, data,worker, e);

    }

    private void WorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Colors.UnlockData(m_tempImage, data);
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            progressBar1.Value = 0;

        }
        else if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            Colors.UnlockData(m_tempImage, data);
            if(!exit)
            m_imgBox.UpdateImage(m_tempImage);
            MessageBox.Show("Canceled");
            progressBar1.Value = 0;

        }
        else
        {
            Colors.UnlockData(m_tempImage, data);
            if (!exit)
            m_imgBox.UpdateImage(m_tempImage);
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            MessageBox.Show("Done");

        }
    }

    private void WorkerProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

Anybody has any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A proper way to do this would be checking a `backgroundWorker.CancellationPending` and set `e.Cancel = true` from `WorkerDoWork`.

`CancelAsync` does not stop the worker, it just send a message to a thread saying "I would like to stop".

Here is a [full sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20627/BackgroundWorker-Threads-and-Supporting-Cancel).